# Would like a Chrome extension that shows the active request count

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I use the [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com) web pages to update some data about my organization, certain XHR web requests can take up to one minute to complete. (If they take longer than one minute, they fail with 502 from my company proxy.) I can see these incomplete requests in the Network tab of the F12 tools, but I would like a quick way to see whether a request is currently waiting for a response without having to open the F12 tools, which would obscure my page. (Yes, I know you can dock the F12 window to the side of the page. That's not ideal.)

Ideally this would be a number badge on the Extension icon, similar to how uBlock Origin says how many requests were blocked on the current page.

Does any extension like this exist?  Would it be difficult to write?

Comment: You can use chrome.webRequest to monitor requests filtered by type (xmlhttprequest), url, and tab id.